# Gnome On Screen Keyboard appears only in activity search

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 15.04, accessibility, onscreen-keyboard

I use a Dell with a touch screen which can be folded into a laptop with Ubuntu 15.04 (Gnome).

I enabled the Gnome On Screen Keyboard in the Accessibility menu, but the onscreen keyboard appears only when i select the Activities search box. Whenever I select any other text input (i.e. browser, gedit) it does not show.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but it seems that this is a known problem. 
I also cannot get it to work and there is already a bug report.
[bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=744551)